# How to access value from fetch call in a variable in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

How to assign value in a variable in the Fetch call of react.
As I have made 2 API call one after another using map in JS
Was Facing the issue of how we can access data from another function

```
var data = ""
fetch(url,{})
.then((res)=> res.json())
.then((output) => data = output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const numberOfProject = (project_id,callback) => {
        var numprj;
        fetch(accountUrl,{
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({"project_id": project_id})
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => numprj = data)
        .then(() => callback(numprj))
    }
```

Now Call the function with call back

```
numberOfProject(item.project_id, getData)
```

Now in getData, we will receive the data

```
const getData = (response) => {
                    projNum = response
                    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>2",projNum)
                }
```